# capturing click events on web-browser scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

is it possible to capture a click event on a scrollbar? I have some code where i am observing the click and mousedown events on the document. However, it seems that when I click on the scrollbar, the event is not captured. This leads me to believe that the scrollbars aren't really part of the document. (Assumption :-)) Is this a correct assumption?  What is the right way to do this so that the behaviour is consistent across all major browsers?

sample code

```
document.observe('click', function(evt){
    //do something
    //blah blah blah
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. The closest you can get is the scroll event. It'll work on every element that has a scrollbar, and it will fire on both mouse scroll with scroll bar, scroll wheel, arrow keys, page up/down, etc. Here's a brief jQuery example.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    console.log("foo")
});
```

That's the best suggestion I can give you - I can't imagine any other uses for a scroll bar click event.